# Abrir calendário do Input type month ao clicar em qualquer parte do campo

Tags: javascript, html

o calendario só abre por padrão, ao clicar na seta a direita, há algum jeito de abrir o calendário ao clicar em qualquer parte do campo?

```html
<input type='month' value='2018-01'>
```

Comment: Olá Guilerme. Sua pergunta está muito vaga. Dá uma lida [nesta página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode-se fazer isso usando `CSS`

```css
input[type="month"] {
    position: relative;
}

input[type="month"]:after {
    content: "\25BC"; 
    color: #555;
    padding: 0 5px;
}


input[type="month"]:hover:after {
    color: #bf1400;
}
input[type="month"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    color: transparent;
    background: transparent;
}


input[type="month"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    z-index: 1;
}


 input[type="month"]::-webkit-clear-button {
     z-index: 1;
 }
```

```html
<input type='month' value='2018-01' class='input-container'>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado cara! :D